# Fire API call only when a Vue Router child route is hit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue2 and vue router 3x. How can I execute a store action whenever a specific child route is hit regardless if it is hit through a button press or the browser back/forward buttons?

I need to fire off an API call whenever a specific **child** route is hit. Currently the code works fine, however, the second a user presses the browsers back/forward buttons it breaks.

Here is a breakdown of the problem...

The way my router is setup is like:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/browse/food/:foodId',
      name: 'Food',
      component: foodComp,
      children: [
        {
          path: ':routeTitle',
          name: 'FoodDescription',
          component: foodDescriptionComp,
          props: {
            viewMode: 'TEXT',
          },
        },
        {
          path: ':routeTitle',
          name: 'FoodImage',
          component: foodDescriptionComp,
          props: {
            viewMode: 'IMAGE',
          },
        },
        {
          path: ':routeTitle/food-translation',
          name: 'FoodTranslation',
          component: foodTranslationComp,
        },
      ],
    },
    ...lotsOfOtherRoutes,
  ],
});
```

...the `foodDescriptionComp` has pagination built into it to flip between different foods, that is trigger on click of the "next page" (or page number) button, and that `method` is setup like this:

```
methods: {
  switchPage(pageNumber, foodIdForPageSelection) {
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'FoodDescription',
      params: { foodId: foodIdForPageSelection },
    });

    await this.loadFoodByPage({
      catalogId: this.catalogId,
      pageNumber,
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see the page router will update the route and then as a separate action I call `loadFoodByPage`. As mentioned above, this works great, but if a user tries to use their browsers back button instead then the `loadFoodByPage` will never be called.

I have tried a few things to solve this:

I have tried adding `beforeEnter` and moving the `loadFoodByPage` to the `beforeEnter`, however, that is only hit on the initial page load.

I believe using `beforeEach` would work but we have hundreds of routes in our application and it seems silly to add logic for this one specific child route that will be checked on every single page.

I've tried getting really hacky, but this solution below does not work as it only maintains the history one press back - so for example if I go from the login page then redirect to the food 1, then go to  2, 3, 4 and I press the back button in the browser it will go back and load page 3, then I press back again and it goes to the login page. Even if this approach did work, it feels extremely anti-pattern.

```
// Back/Forward browser button pressed
window.onpopstate = function () {
  window.location.reload();
};
```

Comment: Do not use a window event, the solution should be done 'within vue'. You'll need to add a watcher to your `foodDescriptionComp`, which will watch the $route.name, and if  `page.to === 'myChildRoute'`, then call `loadFoodByPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but this should work in principle. The idea being this will be triggered per route change, with the page number being set in the URL. If there is no page number in the URL then 1 is used.

```js
methods: {
  switchPage(pageNumber, foodIdForPageSelection) {
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'FoodDescription',
      params: { foodId: foodIdForPageSelection },
      query: { pageNumber }
    })
},
watch:{
  '$route' (to, from){
    if(to.name === 'FoodDescription') {
      this.loadFoodByPage({
        catalogId: this.catalogId,
        pageNumber: this.pageNumber ? this.pageNumber : 1,
    });
    }
  }
},
computed: {
  pageNumber: () => {
      return this.$route.query.pageNumber;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> have tried a few things to solve this:
>
> I have tried adding **beforeEnter** and moving the **loadFoodByPage** to the **beforeEnter**, however, that is only hit on the initial page load.
>
> I believe using **beforeEach** would work but we have hundreds of routes in our application and it seems silly to add logic for this one specific child route that will be checked on every single page.

Yes, you can use the `beforeEnter` or `beforeEach` to achieve this.

**beforeEnter** - you've already tried this approach and found that it only works on the initial page load. This is because the `beforeEnter` is not re-evaluated when navigating back to a route using the browser's back button.

**beforeEach** - this executed before each route is entered, including when navigating back to a route using the browser's back button but you're concerned about the performance implications of adding this guard to all routes in your application.

So, a potential solution here is to use a dynamic module for your route. This way, you can add the `beforeEnter` to apply only the routes that need it, without having to add it to every route.

Example;

```
// Dynamic route module
const foodDescriptionModule = {
 beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
   // Call your API here
   await store.dispatch('loadFoodByPage', {
     catalogId: to.params.catalogId,
     pageNumber: to.params.pageNumber,
   });

   next();
 },
 children: [
   {
     path: ':routeTitle',
     name: 'FoodDescription',
     component: foodDescriptionComp,
     props: {
       viewMode: 'TEXT',
     },
   },
   {
     path: ':routeTitle',
     name: 'FoodImage',
     component: foodDescriptionComp,
     props: {
       viewMode: 'IMAGE',
     },
   },
   {
     path: ':routeTitle/food-translation',
     name: 'FoodTranslation',
     component: foodTranslationComp,
   },
 ],
};

// Main router configuration
const router = new Router({
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [
   {
     path: '/browse/food/:foodId',
     name: 'Food',
     component: foodComp,
     children: [foodDescriptionModule],
   },
   ...lotsOfOtherRoutes,
 ],
});
```

Here, the `beforeEnter` guard is defined in a separate module (`foodDescriptionModule`). This module is then included in the `children` array of the main route configuration. This way, the `beforeEnter` guard is only applied to the routes defined in `foodDescriptionModule`, and not to every route in your application.

Please note that this assumes that the `loadFoodByPage` action is available in your vuex store. If this is not the case, you will need to adjust the code accordingly. Remember then to import the vuex store at the top of your file by a `import store from './store'`. This solution should allow you to execute a store action whenever a specific child route is hit, regardless of whether the route is hit through a button press or the browser's back/forward buttons.

Comment: With this code I'm getting an error of `"path" is required in a route configuration.`

Comment: Should the module have an empty `path` or..?